# Magento 2 Shipping Method I want Ternary condition for thee Like 'LBS' : 'KILOGRAM' :'GRAMS'

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, shipping-methods, magento-community, product-weight

I am using shipping method in Magento2 my website.but this shipping method only two weight unit support so I want three weight unit support.
my code is below, so help me

```
public function getStoreWeightUnit($storeId)
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            'general/locale/weight_unit',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            $storeId
       // ) == 'lbs' ? 'LBS' : 'KILOGRAM';
        ) == 'grams' ? 'GRAMS' :'KILOGRAM':'kbs' ? 'lbs':'LBS' ;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

public function getStoreWeightUnit($storeId)
    {

$weightUnit =$this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            'general/locale/weight_unit',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            $storeId);

$unit = ($weightUnit == 'grams') ? 'GRAMS' : (($weightUnit == 'kbs')  ? 'KILOGRAM' : 'LBS');

return $unit;

}

Comment: Let me know if any issues

Comment: ok i am now check and update you sir thank you

Comment: this code is helpfull to me thank you sir

Comment: No issues let me if any issues